# How to get data from private google sheet after user sign in with their Google account?

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm developing an Android app, it include a feature that after user sign in with their Google account we will access their google sheets to get database. I have tried to search for Google Spreadsheet Api but not clear how to use it.

Of course I can get data from public sheets from the code below, but the problem is getting private sheets.

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
            String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
            if (values != null) {
                results.add("Name, Major");
                for (List row : values) {
                    results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(4));
                }
            }


            return results;
        }
```

I also searched somewhere and found the code below but it throws NoSuchMethodError exception, and I confused what is "username" and "password" in the line spreadsheet.setUserCredentials.

```
SpreadsheetService spreadsheet= new SpreadsheetService("v1");
    spreadsheet.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    try {
        spreadsheet.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
        URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = spreadsheet.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);

        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
        for (SpreadsheetEntry service : spreadsheets) {             
            System.out.println(service.getTitle().getPlainText());
       }
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So anyone know how to do this or have sample code please share me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution to my question, and now I am posting here to help anyone else facing the same problem to overcome it.

- First of all, go to https://console.developers.google.com and create new OAuth client ID credential associated with your project.
- Now in your android project, add these libraries in dependencies:

  ```
  dependencies {    
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'    
      compile files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')    
      compile files('libs/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar')    
      compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')    
      compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0-sources.jar')    
      compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar')    
      compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar')    
      compile files('libs/guava-10.0.1.jar')    
      compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')    
  }
  ```
- In AndroidManifest.xml add these permissions:
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
- Also add this in `<application></application>` tag:

  `<meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
- And the CODE is as follows:

  ```
  public class DownloadDatabaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private static final String TAG = "my_log";
      public static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
      String spreadsheetName;
      String worksheetName;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_database);

          Button btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
          btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  EditText etSpreadsheetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSpreadsheetName);
                  EditText etWorksheetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWorksheetName);
                  spreadsheetName = etSpreadsheetName.getText().toString();
                  worksheetName = etWorksheetName.getText().toString();

                  Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                          new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
              }
          });
      }

      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              Log.d(TAG, "--> enter first if");

              final String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
              new DownloadTask(this).execute(accountName, spreadsheetName, worksheetName);

          } else if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              Log.d(TAG, "--> enter second if");
          }
      }

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          private Context context;

          // constructor
          public DownloadTask(Context context) {
              this.context = context;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              showProgressDialog(context);
          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              String mEmail = params[0]; // your google account name
              String mType = "com.google";
              Account account = new Account(mEmail, mType);
              String scopes = "oauth2:https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds "
                      + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login "
                      + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
              String token = null;
              try {
                  token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
              } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                  Intent recoveryIntent = e.getIntent();
                  startActivityForResult(recoveryIntent, 2);
              } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
              }

              try {
                  SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
                  service.setAuthSubToken(token);
                  URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                          "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
                  SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
                  List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

                  Log.d(TAG, "spreadsheets.size() = " + spreadsheets.size());

                  for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) { // outer for loop
                      if (spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText().equalsIgnoreCase(params[1])) { // your spreadsheet name
                          List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = spreadsheet.getWorksheets();

                          for (WorksheetEntry worksheet : worksheets) { // inner for loop
                              String title = worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText();
                              if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(params[2])) { // your worksheet name
                                  Log.d(TAG, "Worksheet name: " + title);
                                  URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
                                  ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
                                  Log.d(TAG, "Number of row = " + listFeed.getTotalResults());

                                  // scan through each row in worksheet
                                  for (ListEntry row : listFeed.getEntries()) {
                                      String rowTitle = row.getTitle().getPlainText();
                                      ArrayList<String> currentRow = new ArrayList<>();

                                      // get elements in current row stored in ArrayList
                                      for (String element : row.getCustomElements().getTags()) {
                                          if (!row.getCustomElements().getValue(element).equals(rowTitle))
                                              currentRow.add(row.getCustomElements().getValue(element));
                                      }
                                      // Log.d(TAG, "currentRow.size() = "+currentRow.size());

                                      // do your work here with the data received

                                  }`
                                  break; // break inner
                              }
                          }
                          break; // break outer
                      }
                  }

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

              return token;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Token Value: " + token);
              hideProgressDialog();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The username and password that you set in the `setUserCredentials` are the credentials that you use to authenticate the request to the server. For your question on how to get the private sheets, I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections) can help you with that. For more example and information, check this [example code](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService).